# React event listener with throttle not being removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, throttling

My code look something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize);
}

resize = () => this.forceUpdate();
```

This works fine. But then I tried adding a throttle for better performance

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', _.throttle(this.resize, 200));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize);
}

resize = () => this.forceUpdate();
```

But then when I resize the screen in a different view I get this error warning:

```
Warning: forceUpdate(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called forceUpdate() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the component.
```

That means I didn't correctly remove the listener. How do I remove a listener with a throttle? Or should I put the throttle somewhere else?

I tried updating `componentWillUnmount` likes this:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', _.throttle(this.resize, 200));
}
```

but this did not work either.

Any ideas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you could setup the throttle in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
   ...
   this.throttledResize = _.throttle(this.resize, 200)
}

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.throttledResize);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.throttledResize);
}
```

To elaborate on why this works, `window.removeEventListener` has to look at all registered event listeners for the target and event, and does an equality check on the event handler that was passed to it - if it finds a match, it removes it. Here is a naive implementation of that:

```
window.removeEventListener = function(event, handler) {
   // remove the supplied handler from the registered event handlers
   this.eventHandlers[event] = this.eventHandlers[event].filter((evtHandler) => {
       return evtHandler !== handler;
   })
}
```

`_.throttle` returns a new function every time you run it; therefore, the equality check will always fail and you will be unable to remove the event listener (without removing *all* event listeners). Here is a simple demonstration of what is happening in the equality check:

```js
function foo() {}
function generateFunction() { 
   // just like throttle, this creates a new function each time it is called
   return function() {} 
}

console.log(foo === foo) // true
console.log(generateFunction() === generateFunction()) // false
```